# Embed Google Cloud Monitoring Dashboard/Widget to external page

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I'm migrating from Librato to Google Cloud Monitoring and I like to embed a dashboard/widget to an external page (think intranet). Not finding anything in the docs at all with regards to this.

Does anyone know if it's possible?

My backup plan is to use the API to get the data and graph it myself https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/reading-metrics

Answer (score 2):

You can export the Cloud Monitoring data to [Grafana](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/google-cloud-monitoring/), and them use a Grafana [embedded link](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/sharing/share-panel/).