# It is possible to make GCP web interface compatible with iframe HTML tag?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, iframe, cloud

I'm currently working on a project where I want to have access to log data and other stuff
like graph from GCP on a web application.
For security reasons (I guess), it's not possible to integrate a GCP adress in an  tag. Do you know any way to make it work or do you have any idea for something that would make the data accessible ?

Answer (score 1):

You might refer to [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging) for logs, and [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring) for metrics and visualization that are the part of Cloud Operation Suite. I believe almost all of the visualizations you see on Google Cloud Console (Web UI) are from Cloud Monitoring. Both of them have API and SDK that can be accessed using popular languages like Python, Java, or JavaScript. Cloud Monitoring itself supports creating visualization in Widgets and combining them all on [Dashboards](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/dashboards).

For the embedding with IFrame part, I haven't seen a direct way to do that, as it will need to do authentication to view Cloud Monitoring dashboards. According to this answer, [you can export the visualization from Grafana instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67640753/3054766). But I haven't tried that approach yet.

About the GCP address in a tag. Can you elaborate more about that in the comment below? I can suggest that all the resources in GCP have their own resource name that you can filter from the Metric Explore in Cloud Monitoring. Custom tags are supported, you can put any valid name you like.